# how do you group query by hours?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to query surveys completed every hour in a given day.
the survey table is something like this:

**id**(SERIAL) - **userid**(INTEGER) - **description** - **timeTaken**(timestamp with time zone)

```
3 ;   1;   "some random description";  "2015-01-17 04:30:24.983576-05"
5 ;   2;   "sample about x";  "2015-01-17 04:30:24.983576-05"
7 ;   3;   "survey about ducks";  "2015-01-17 05:30:24.983576-05"
```

basically for a given day lets say March 1st, I want to get all the survey rows grouped by the hour they were taken, i.e 7 rows at 1pm, 3 at 2pm, etc. But I'm not sure if its possible to group like this on pg or if I should do it client end.

**EDIT:** for the data above have id 3 and 5 grouped under 4 and id 7 grouped for 5. basically I want to display the data seperated by the hours they were completed in.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample data

Comment: Show your expected output with respect to the given data

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_part to extract just the hour, which you can have in your group by clause.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html.

Answer (score 0):

By using [extarct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function in postgresql

for the following sample data

```
id userid descp                   timetaken                   
-- ------ ----------------------- --------------------------- 
1  1      some random description 2015-01-17 15:00:24.9835760 
2  2      sample about x          2015-01-17 15:00:24.9835760 
3  3      survey about ducks      2015-01-17 16:00:24.9835760 
4  3      survey about ducks      2015-01-01 19:00:24.9835760 
5  3      survey about ducks      2015-01-01 16:00:24.9835760 
6  3      survey about ducks      2015-01-01 19:00:24.9835760
```

I need to get the survey_count per hour in date `01-01-2015`

```
   select extract(hour  from timetaken)  survey_hour
          ,count(*) survey_count
   from sur
   where timetaken::date  ='2015-01-01'
   group by survey_hour
```